# Must this upper bound on mixing time depend on the minimum stationary probability?

Tags: markov-chains, mixing

It is known fact that for a finite-state, reversible and ergodic Markov chain with transition matrix $M$, the following control on the mixing time holds

$$\left( \frac{1}{\gamma_\star - 1}\right)\ln{2} \leq t_{mix} \leq \frac{\ln(4/\pi_\star)}{\gamma_\star}$$

where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution $\pi M = \pi$,
$$\pi_\star = \min_i \pi(i),$$
the mixing time is defined by
$$t_{mix} = \min \{t \geq 1 : \sup_{\mu} \|\mu M^{t-1} - \pi\|_{TV} \leq 1/4\},$$
and the absolute spectral gap 
$$\gamma_\star = 1 - \max \{\lambda_2(M), |\lambda_d(M)|\}.$$

Is the upper bound tight on all the parameters ? Specifically, is the dependence on $\pi_\star$ generally known to be necessary ?

Comment: See this related question and answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217464/how-much-larger-than-the-relaxation-time-can-the-mixing-time-be?rq=1